# Updating culture short time pattern format not getting in DateTime.now

Tags: c#, datetime, culture

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern="DD/MM/YYYY";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern ="hh:mm tt";
```

I am overriding the Date and time format for a culture in thread by doing this we will get `Date` and `Time` in given format in `DateTime.Now`.

I am able to get preferred format for `Date` same thing not working for Time.

How to get time in preferred format using above culture threading.

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please create a [MCVE] demonstrate your problem? It is _really_ hard to understand without it. Also it would be better to read [FAQ] and [ask] a few times..

Comment: edited the question hope you get my problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to create an object of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' and set the date and time format specifications on that object.

Next you need to set the current culture of your thread to that culture.

I have given the code for your reference below

```
private void UpdateCurrentCulture()
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo objCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

        objCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        objCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "hh:mm tt";

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = objCulture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = objCulture;

        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
    }
```

Comment: @bharathp.v Anytime mate !